# Rails add link to edit attribute from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a model Product and a model Category.

I have a table in products index showing products with columns like:

```
 <td><%= product.ID %></td>
 <td><%= product.NAME %></td>
 <td><%= product.category.NAME %></td>
```

It shows values like:

1,salad, vegetable

2,apple,fruit

I want to be able to click on vegetable or fruit to edit them.

I tried:

```
<td><%= link_to product.category.NAME, [:edit, product.category] %>
```

This takes me to a page

> categories/1/edit

which returns

> Couldn't find Product with 'ID'=

Instead it should go to

> categories/edit/1

In my routes I have:

```
 match ':controller(/:action(/:ID))', :via => [:get, :post]
 resources :categories
```

What is the correct syntax to use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke the edit action on the category controller with your modified route specify the controller, action and id values like so:

```
<%= link_to product.category.NAME, { controller: :categories, action: :edit, ID: product.category.id } %>
```

The link_to helper will build the path correctly to match the `category/edit/1` path and route to the edit action of the category controller instead of the product controller (assuming category.id == 1)

Comment: Thanks, but I feel my solution still answers your question - in what way doesn't it? - is there some other criteria?

Comment: According to the values in my example your solution shows 1, /categories/1/edit,vegetable and 1,/categories/2/edit, fruit. And in any case if I click on products/1/edit nothing happens. The link must show category name and when i click on it going to edit page for that category.

Comment: NAME is a column in categories database table.

Comment: hmm, you are still getting `Couldn't find Product with 'ID'=` ? That doesn't seem possible unless your routes are messed up. Try `rake routes` from the terminal and see what action `edit_category` is being mapped to.

Comment: I get: categories#edit category GET      /categories/:id(.:format)

Comment: Note that  I have a categories index view with a table listing categories. Each has a link to edit. If I click it it takes me to categories/edit/1, which works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126992/discussion-between-henners66-and-catmal).